# Определение типа возвращаемого значения из сигнатуры функции, переданной как параметр шаблона C++

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

Как определить тип возвращаемого значения из сигнатуры функции, переданной в параметр шаблона?

```
template <class T> // T хранит сигнатуру функции.
<???> someMethod(someParameters) { // <???> -- тип возвращаемого значения T
    ...
}
```

Comment: Такой вариант —  `template<typename Func>
auto f(Func g) { return g(); }` — вашу задачу не решает? Или вы хотите не передавать саму функцию и вычислять ее? Но не забывайте о перегрузке функций — одно имя функции без аргументов неоднозначно... См. также [`invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of). И да, вы метки лепите "просто так"? Здесь нет ни `rtti` (решение о типе никак не времени выполнения), на шаблонов *проектирования* (для вашего вопроса годится "шаблоны-с++", читайте описание метки "шаблоны"...)

Comment: @Harry, Ваш вариант не подходит, так как ```return g()``` вызывает оператор (). Спасибо про то, что рассказали про invoke_result, он поможет решить проблему. Насчёт меток: когда я искал решение этой проблемы, иногда я видел использование оператора typeid(), реализующего RTTI.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите использовать только тип (чего? вы передаете функцию в качестве аргумента? или хотите при вызове явно *руками* указывать тип функции? тогда почему просто руками же не указать тип возвращаемого значения?)? Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода, как бы вы хотели использовать данную возможность. По вашему вопросу это неясно.

Comment: Указать руками при вызове не получится, вопрос конкретный: получить тип возвращаемого значения из сигнатуры. Может быть с ```T``` будут проводиться разные манипуляции и т.п.

Comment: Еще раз. Как именно задается сигнатура? У вас есть объект (функция) определенного типа, и вы используете ее? У вас есть какой-то `typedef/using` и используете это имя? Иначе ваш вопрос, как говорится, о сферическом коне в вакууме :) Что такое "сигнатура" *вообще*?... :(

Comment: Эта сигнатура функции задаётся как параметр шаблона, например ```someMethod<void(int, int)>(...);``` и в этом примере функция возвращает void и принимает 2 параметра типа int и как раз нужно узнать, что возвращает ```void(int, int)``` (в этом примере ответ будет void)

Comment: Потому и спрашивал. Скажем прямо — не вижу ни малейшего смысла писать руками `someMethod<void(int, int)>(...);` вместо `someMethod<void>(...);`. А как использовать по-другому — вы не указываете.

Comment: @Harry Можно написать `someMethod<decltype(foo)>(...`

Comment: @user7860670 О! Уже теплее :) Но с вами и так все понятно :) А `foo` — это что в таком случае? Вызываемый объект?

Comment: @Harry Функция, сигнатуру которой получаем. Собственно а что вас смущает в этом примере? Получить возвращаемое значение и/или аргументы из сигнатуры функции - вроде вполне реалистичный сценарий.

Comment: @user7860670 Ну, тогда можно/нужно указать аргументы (хотя бы для разрешения перегрузки), а это уже дает возможность получения возвращаемого типа без вызова самой функции, нет?

Comment: @Harry, Я предполагаю, вы думаете о том, что в ```someMethod``` передаются параметры той сигнатуры функции. Но мне никто не запрещает написать такую конструкцию: ```someMethod<void(int, int)>("I am a string!");```

Comment: Я не вижу, в чем разница — написать нечто сложное для выдирания `void` из `void(int, int)` (и при этом писать само `void(int, int)`), или просто написать `void`? Как по мне проще, меньше вводить, меньше шансов ошибиться. Если же вы  вводите не сам тип, а какую-то переменную-функцию, то опять же `decltype` вполне достаточно, не надо делать ничего особо сложного... Что-то типа https://ideone.com/b14phe

Comment: @Harry Если перегрузка одна, то и указывать аргументы не придется. Ну и вообще, можно подставлять сразу какой-то существующий алис для типа функции.

Comment: @Harry, пример помог, спасибо вам (:

Comment: Чем проще решение, тем оно надежнее :)

Comment: @user7860670 Ну так все зависит от конкретики. Первое ощущение от вопроса было, что это вопрос не как забить гвоздь, а какой рукой держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздя оным...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для извлечения возвращаемого значения из сигнатуры функции придется написать свой трейт, который бы не требовал указания аргументов, работая за счет специализации шаблона. Еще таким образом можно извлечь и типы аргументов.

```
template
<
    typename x_Method
>
class
t_MethodTraits;

template
<
    typename... x_Args
,   typename x_Result
>
class
t_MethodTraits<x_Result (x_Args...)>
{
    public: using
    t_Result = x_Result;
};

template
<
    typename x_Method
>
typename t_MethodTraits<x_Method>::t_Result
someMethod(void) 
{
    return typename t_MethodTraits<x_Method>::t_Result{};
}

int
main()
{
    int * result{someMethod<int * (char, float)>()};
    static_cast<void>(result); // not used
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:35,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:35,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27template%0A%3C%0A++++typename+x_Method%0A%3E%0Aclass%0At_MethodTraits%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate%0A%3C%0A++++typename...+x_Args%0A,+++typename+x_Result%0A%3E%0Aclass%0At_MethodTraits%3Cx_Result+(x_Args...)%3E%0A%7B%0A++++public:+using%0A++++t_Result+%3D+x_Result%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%0A%3C%0A++++typename+x_Method%0A%3E%0Atypename+t_MethodTraits%3Cx_Method%3E::t_Result+someMethod()+%0A%7B%0A++++return+typename+t_MethodTraits%3Cx_Method%3E::t_Result%7B%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++int+*+result%7BsomeMethod%3Cint+*+(char,+float)%3E()%7D%3B%0A++++static_cast%3Cvoid%3E(result)%3B+//+not+used%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g131,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wconversion+-Wpedantic+-Werror%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)